# BDE inmem000.rem access/sharing violation

Tags: session, iis-6, access-violation, bde, cgi-bin

I have this proprietary web CGI executable which opens a connection to a BDE Thingy each time a page is requested.

I do know nothing of the workings of that compiled exe, nor of BDE, but I observed that during each page request BDE generates a temporary INMEM000.REM file.

The problem is that during heavy load on the server, page generation can last some time, during which it's impossible for any other user to request another page, as BDE tries to create/lock that same INMEM000.REM file.

I've found some info that the file has something to do with application sessions towards BDE.

But why does BDE perseveres on that same file ? Can't it be instructed to create multiple session lockfiles ? Or is it application dependent, and should it be encoded in the CGI part ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with old technology is, less people complain about.

The solution was simple, the folder wherein the INMEM000.REM file was generated had too restrictive access rights. BDE could only generate 1 lock/temp file, only god knows why.

Once the access rights were set loose, a distant child laughed, BDE screamed and soared and INMEM###.REM files filled the folder.

Joy fell upon the earth, and it was good.